# How to show magento global message in pop up - Magento 2

Tags: ajax, magento-2.1.7, modal-popup

I have created an ajaxcart custom plugin but I want to show the global message in which appear behind the ajax pop up.

[image]

Comment: this can be css issue , elements overlapping

Comment: popup over lapping the error message , try using  z indexing

Comment: Have you got any solution?